# Why Visual studio is forcing me to login to azure using Organizational Account

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to publish a website to Azure from VS 2013. It is always showing me the login screen with Organization account. Sometimes in between it shows both the options in the login screen i.e. using Microsoft account or Organization account.

Why it is not showing both the account options all the time? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: When you login to Azure portal , it should provide you 2 option after putting username/password, one personal account and other is organization account, did you get these type?

Comment: No sir, it is only giving me one option of login using organization account. Is there any cookie VS store somewhere in the temp folder?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a definitive answer, but hopefully will shed some light on the situation.

Everything in Azure is linked to an Azure active directory.  Azure uses a feature called Home Realm Discovery to determine the appropriate AAD instance for a user.  Basically it runs several checks on the @xxx.yyy portion of your email/login id.

- If it's xxx.onmicrosoft.com, then xxx is the AAD tenant.
- Otherwise, it looks for any custom domain matching xxx.yyy and uses the associated AAD tenant.

Since Microsoft Accounts can be associated with multiple directories they can not be used for Home Realm Discovery.

My *guess* is that if VS doesn't know which directory you're targeting it forces you to use an org account so it can "discover" it.  If it already knows the directory and just needs to authenticate you to it then it allows you to use either a a Microsoft account or an organizational account.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. VS2012 published to Azure using the same profile just fine.

I found this. It sounds promising. I'll test tomorrow:
http://www.nguyenquyhy.com/2014/10/an-error-occurred-while-creating-the-webjob-schedule/